# Not Selecting All Elements Though All Are Detected

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, geckodriver

I have a script that clicks "show more" at the bottom of [this page](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/mate-x-most-affordable-fully-loaded-folding-ebike-love-design#/comments) four times to expose additional comment threads.

Even though my `XPATH` will select all of the "See 1 more reply.../See N more replies..." elements, the script never ends up clicking all of them. (At the time of writing this, it clicks only 7 of the 13 elements.)

**XPath Selector**

`//ui-view//a[contains(@class, "commentAction")]`

**The Part of the Script** (It's quite lengthy, so just let me know if you want/need to see more of it.):

```
tab_comments = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@gogo-test="comments_tab"]')

if len(tab_comments) > 0:

    browser.implicitly_wait(5)

    try:
        comments_count = int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, str(tab_comments[0].text))))
    except ValueError:
        comments_count = 0

    if comments_count > 0:
        # 1. Switch to Comments Tab
        tab_comments[0].click()

        # 2. Expose Additional Threads
        show_more_comments = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//ui-view//a[text()="show more"]'))
        )

        clicks = 0
        while clicks <= 3:
            try:
                clicks += 1
                show_more_comments.click()
            except Exception:
                break

        # 3. Expand All Threads
        see_n_more_replies = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//ui-view//a[contains(@class, "commentAction")]')
        for idx, see_replies in enumerate(see_n_more_replies):
            print('\n\n\n\nidx: ' + str(idx) + '\n\n\n\n')
            see_replies.click()
```

**Do the buttons need to be in view in order to click them?** (This doesn't seem to be the case for the other ones, but at this point I'm grasping at straws.)

The issue is that I parse the comments in step `# 4. ...`, and since it doesn't expand all of the threads with more than one response, which is what it's supposed to do, those fields turn up empty in the logs.

No errors or exceptions are thrown.

I'm using ***Firefox/geckodriver.***

Answer (score 1):

Execute the following code snippet to load all the comments on the page by clicking on 'show more' till the show more link disappears

```
comment_pages = 0
no_of_comments = len(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('desktop-comment'))
while True:
    show_more_link = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('show more')
    if len(show_more_link) == 0:  # if the 'show more' link does not exist on the page
        break
    # before clicking on the link, it is important to bring the link inside the viewport. Otherwise `ElementNotVisible` exception is encountered
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', show_more_link[0])
    show_more_link[0].click()
    try:
        # wait for more comments to load by waiting till the comment count after clicking the button is greater than before the click
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10, poll_frequency=2).until(lambda x: len(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('desktop-comment')) > no_of_comments)
    except:
        break
    no_of_comments = len(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('desktop-comment'))
    comment_pages += 1
```

After executing this code your dom contains the contents of all the comments. Post which you start your actual scraping of the page.

```
comments = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('desktop-comment')
for comment in comments:
    author = comment.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='commentLayout-header']/a[contains(@href, 'individuals')]").text
    print 'Comment by person : ' + author

    has_more_replies = len(comment.find_elements_by_partial_link_text("more replies...")) > 0
    if has_more_replies:
        more_replies = comment.find_element_by_partial_link_text("more replies...")
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()', more_replies)
        more_replies.click()
    reply_count = len(comment.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@class, 'commentLayout-reply')]"))
    print 'Number of replies to the comment : ' + str(reply_count)
    print '-------------------------------------------------------------------'
```

The output of which is as follows:

> ```
> Comment by person : Jeff Rudd
> Number of replies to the comment : 1
> -------------------------------------------------------------------
> Comment by person : Martin Boyle
> Number of replies to the comment : 1
> -------------------------------------------------------------------
> Comment by person : John Bickerton
> Number of replies to the comment : 1
> -------------------------------------------------------------------
> Comment by person : Mikkel Taanning
> Number of replies to the comment : 2
> -------------------------------------------------------------------
> Comment by person : Christopher Sams
> Number of replies to the comment : 2
> -------------------------------------------------------------------
> Comment by person : Marc Vieux
> Number of replies to the comment : 2
> -------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```
>
> ........................

You can modify the for loop to get more details of the comments

Comment: Feel free to use the method `move_to_element` from `ActionChains` class, if you don't want to use `scrollIntoView` method of JS. It shouldn't make a difference. To answer your other questions, yes I have tested this, yes it actually return all the elements. I truncated the output in my answer to maintain brevity. Add `move_to_element` to your code before you perform the click and see if that helps.

Comment: i was wondering why use javascript at all? have you tested the code i provided? i'm wondering why that code doesn't work? do i really have to scroll the items into view so that they're clickable with selenium?

Comment: Didn't I mention an alternative to the JavaScript in my previous comment?- use `move_to_element`. I will test your code in sometime and get back to you. One thing that you have to keep in mind while using selenium web driver is that it emulates an user actions on the page(or at least tries to). So for an user to click on something, he first needs to see it. I am curious as to what your reservation against scrolling the item into view is.

Comment: oh whoops i hadnt even really looked at your code until now and i just assumed u were doing much more with javascript than you actually are. my question remains: was the issue that it needed to scroll each element into view? ill mark this as the answer if moving to the elements before clicking them works

Comment: Make sure you add appropriate waits in your code. for example: in your while loop, you click on the "show more" link 4 times in quick successions without waiting for the UI to respond to your clicks. This should be avoided and can be handled by adding explicit waits in your code. `scrollIntoView` and `move_to_element` make the code more immune to pesky the `ElementNotVisibleException`.

Comment: ohhh righhhhhhht i can use `WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until( run my code )`. idk i must be getting old. ive been wanting to do this throughout my code, but i "assumed"? i could only use explicit waits with EC and didnt piece it together for some reason until just now. must be getting old :/ i was using `browser.implicitly_wait(N)` throughout my code thinking that it would do what explicit waits do just up until yesterday... lol

Comment: gtg bed ill test it tomo

Comment: Can you accept my response as the answer if you have had a chance to test it out for yourself?

Comment: it wasn't *the* solution to the issue. ive marked it as helpful since it was indeed helpful